# why option to choose unity 8 is not shown in sddm?

Tags: kubuntu, unity8, sddm

I decided to try unity8 on my kubuntu system.

```
______________________________________________________________________________________________
android@android  :18:23:55  ~
--> sudo apt install --reinstall  unity8-desktop-session-mir
[sudo] password for android: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  darkplaces libode4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,790 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 unity8-desktop-session-mir all 1.0.12+15.10.20150609-0ubuntu1 [4,790 B]
Fetched 4,790 B in 0s (17.0 kB/s)                     
(Reading database ... 332564 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity8-desktop-session-mir_1.0.12+15.10.20150609-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity8-desktop-session-mir (1.0.12+15.10.20150609-0ubuntu1) over (1.0.12+15.10.20150609-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity8-desktop-session-mir (1.0.12+15.10.20150609-0ubuntu1) ...
______________________________________________________________________________________________
android@android  :19:20:43  ~
--> sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
______________________________________________________________________________________________
android@android  :19:21:04  ~
--> reboot
```

On rebooting the system, option to choose unity 8 is not shown by sddm. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you have SDDM, I'm guessing you have KDE and not Unity by default. If that's true, and you didn't install any version of Unity besides version 8, then any entry that says it's Unity should be Unity 8.

Comment: yes, i tried to run unity 8 on top of my freshly installed Kubuntu 16.04. So is it not possible to run unity 8 without ubuntu-desktop installed? What should I install extra?

Comment: So there's no Unity entry at all?

Comment: yes. no unity entry at all. So how should i get that?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think you do "need" default Ubuntu to use Unity 8, so try installing all the Unity/Ubuntu Desktop stuff.

Comment: okay i had thought of that.. and i wanted to avoid "Unity/Ubuntu Desktop stuff" which i guess is unity 7 in first place.

Comment: You could always experiment in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

sddm can only launch X11 and Wayland sessions. Either ask Canonical to port Unity8 to Wayland or switch to whatever login manager Ubuntu uses these days – probably LightDM.

Answer (score 0):

Your display manager (in your case, SDDM) needs to support the Mir display server.  Canonical has only supported their display server project (LightDM), other projects will need to add their own support.